# Geometric probability (dealing with integer numbers)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are chosen from $\{1,2,\dots N\}$ with replacement. Let $p_N$ be the probability that $a^2+b^2\leq N^2$. What is the value of $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}{p_N}$?

With real numbers, I would just use the geometric approach: $\frac{\pi\cdot N^2/4}{N^2}$ so the limit as $N\to \infty$ equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I guess it's not the same in this particular problem where we deal with integer numbers. The answer, according to the problem book, is the same. Is that a coincidence or what?

Comment: look up the gauss circle problem

Comment: If you draw the quarter circle of radius $N$, these are the integer-valued lattice points inside the quarter circle.  So it's totally not a coincidence that as $N\to \infty$ the result tends to the real-number version.

Comment: Thank you! That's beautiful!

Comment: An alternative way to look at it, is to see that $P(a^2 + b^2 \leq N^2) = P( (\frac{a}{N} )^2+(\frac{b}{N} )^2 \leq 1)$, where $\frac{a}{N} , \frac{b}{N} \in \{ \frac{1}{N}, \frac{2}{N}, \dots , 1 \}$

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen, can you please elaborate. I understand that this is an equivalent problem statement but how does that help?

Comment: It can help in two ways. The probability theory approach: Realize that $\frac{a}{N}$ and $\frac{b}{N}$ both converges towards a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, and therefore in the limit, we get the same as for the continous approach.
The geometric approach: as N increases, the set $\{\frac{1}{N},\frac{2}{N},\dots ,1 \}^2$ will divide the unit square into $\frac{1}{N^2}$ small squares. Counting the proportion of small squares that lie within the (quarter) unit circle corresponds to approximating the area using smaller and smaller squares.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n$ denote the number of lattice points on or inside the quarter of the circle $x^2+y^2=n^2$ that lies in the positive quadrant. We can show (by simple counting) that $$C_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \sqrt{n^2 - k^2} \rfloor.$$ Note, here we don't have to include the points on the x and y axes, so we should subtract a term of $O(n)$ from the above $C_n.$ Furthermore, $x-1 < \lfloor x\rfloor\le x,$ hence $D_n = \#\{ (x, y) : x^2+y^2\le n^2 \text{ and } x,y = 1,2,\dots, n\}$ equals $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^2 - k^2}+O(n).$$ The required probability is given by $$p_n =\frac{D_n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^2 - k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$ As $n\to\infty,$ the RHS converges to $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx,$ which equals $\pi/4,$ because it calculates the area of a quarter of the unit circle.